The ability to resize a textarea goes away when the text exceeds the textarea height and the scrollbar width is set to 0
This took me a while to fix, and was frustrating.
With this in the css:
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
}

When a textarea's content exceeds it's height it is no longer resizable as it appears that the resize widget then forms part of the hidden scroll bar.

Could you create a runnable snippet which definitely shows the problem, and tell us what OS and browser you are using as currently I cannot recreate the problem. Use the <> icon in the editor to include runnable code.

To continue with the general zero widht scrollbar, I overrode the css for textareas by adding:
textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1rem;
}


Here is a solution to allow resizing of textarea without showing the scrollbar:


        textarea {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            resize: both; /* Allow resizing */
            overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbar */
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        /* Hide the scrollbar */
        textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
 <textarea placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>



